# SQL Server Error converting data type nvarchar to date python

Tags: python, date, stored-procedures

I am getting an error while calling a SQL Server stored procedure in python.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to date.

My code is as below.

```
from datetime import datetime

OnlyDate=datetime.now().date()

# I got date in OnlyDate in this formate :-2016-06-30

self.con.execute("exec dbo.ScrapeStatistics_SP @Op='6',@EndTime=now,@Site='testing',@ScrapeType='Category',@Date=OnlyDate")                 
self.con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Date=OnlyDate`

You are trying to insert the string `OnlyDate` into the `Date` column, therefore ending up with an error that nvarchar (`"OnlyDate"`) can't be converted to date.

You should use a parameterized query:

```
query = "exec dbo.ScrapeStatistics_SP @Op='6',@EndTime=now,@Site='testing',
           @ScrapeType='Category',@Date=?"

self.con.execute(query , (OnlyDate,))  # note the comma! this needs to be a tuple
```